# How to tunnel port 25565 through SSH?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

I want to play a game which is hosted on port 25565 (minecraft!), but my university firewall does not allow this port.

I have a dedicated server running linux not too far from uni, so I think there's a way to tunnel through it (but I've never done this before and have no knowledge/experience of tunnelling)

It would probably be slow, but it's better than not being able to play at all. Is it possible to do using only SSH, or do I need other client/server software? My server has OpenSSH installed. Also, the computer I'm using to play the game is running Ubuntu.

I've tried searching but there seem to be so many different solutions to different types of problem =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (Client Side APP). You should not need anything on the remote side except firewall rules to allow out going connections

Setup:

1. Within putty setup a new connection
   to your unix box.(Add the host details etc , don't connect yet)
2. Once that is all setup go to
   Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels in the
   putty tree view.
3. Next enter 25565 into the source
   port and leave the destination
   blank.
4. Finally select dynamic on the first
   combo box.
5. Make sure you save everything then
   finally click the open button

This will create a tunnel on port 25565 locally to any destination on the remote site. This also assumes that you can tunnel a minecraft connection (you might need to set your IE settings to use the the SSH tunnel as well since games sometimes use this if they cant get a connection)

If you cant tunnel minecraft by default use a app like [proxy cap](http://www.proxycap.com/) to force all out going connections through the tunnel.

Comment: Minecraft doesn't let me choose a proxy, it just connects directly. I found out how to set up a proxy and set it to apply systemwide and it works for firefox etc, but minecraft just ignores it. Do you mean Internet Explorer by IE? If so, I'm on linux :)

Comment: Sorry I assumed that you were using windows , But linux has the same option (well at least ubuntu does). If you go to System -> Preferences -> Network Proxy , you should be able to route all or most of the traffic through the proxy. On linux you can also use proxytunnel to tunnel through http proxies (if thats what you have available)

Comment: What about on a mac?

Comment: @Foxtrot You can do the exact same thing on the mac , instead of using putty , use the Terminal application and the following command ssh <username>@<servername>  -D 25565 , once that is connected you can change you system proxy by going to <Apple Icon> -> Preferences -> Network and then click on advanced for you current active network connection. Finally click proxies and enter the details into the Socks Proxy option and make sure its ticked

Answer (score 11):

### I have drawn some sketches

For making it easier to understand the tunnel mechanisms, watch these sketches.
The machine, where the ssh tunnel command is typed is called **»your host«**.

[image: ssh tunnel starting from local]

---

[image: ssh tunnel starting from remote]

### Introduction

1. local: `-L Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.`

   `ssh -L sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **local** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from the `connectToHost` machine.
2. remote: `-R Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.`

   `ssh -R sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **remote** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from your local machine.

### Your example

The second image represents your scenario. The `remotehost` is your *dedicated server running linux not too far from uni*. The `farawayhost` is the blocked minecraft server you want to connect to on its pink port `25565`.

```
 ssh -L 12345:minecraftServerIP:25565 dedicatedServer
```

The port number of the green port is `12345`. You can now access the minecraft server by connecting to

```
localhost:12345
```

Of course you can change the green port’s number `12345` to whatever you want.

Comment: Cool sketches, @erik!

Answer (score 8):

Simple, run the command

```
ssh -L 25565:minecraftserverIp:25565 user@remotelinuxbox
```

Then add a server to your minecraft client localhost:25565

This will allow you to connect to the remote minecraft server via the ssh tunnel.

Comment: I should add you can do this for as many servers as you want just change the first 25565 to any port number and then add a new server to the minecraft client using the new port.

Comment: Edi your answer to include additional relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Try [http-tunnel](http://www.http-tunnel.com/html/). Just go to Settings>Add Ports/Applications and enter the server IP and application port (usually 25565) then press ok and try running minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port Minecraft runs on, so just set it to 22 (because they haven't blocked SSH) then you'll be able to play by specifying the port on each client.

Comment: Not possible if I don't run the server. In the end I asked the host to add a port map on his server from 1863 (MSN, unblocked) to 25565.

Answer (score 0):

Windows users, skip down a bit to the 'under windows' heading.

- **Linux (or UNIX) Users**

  Install a SSH client of some kind (rather obvious)

  Make the following bash (or plain ol' sh) script:

`#! /bin/bash`

`ssh -nfN -D 8080 "<your-ip-or-url-here>"`

`sleep 8`

`java -jar \`

`"/path/to/launcher-for-minecraft.jar"`

You can change how long it 'sleeps' (to make sure that the ssh connection has been initialized) manually if you want. anything else can be changed too.

**follow the steps under the 'Steps to configure minecraft to use this tunnel' heading, and then run the script!

.

- **Windows Users**

  Using PuTTY, I go under 'connection' and allow TCP keep-alives, also setting the number of seconds between keep-alives to 6.

  I then go down to 'SSH -> tunnels' and add a **dynamic** forwarded port for 8080. This is necessary as well as 25565. To accomplish this, do the following:

  Enter `8080` for the 'source port', and `8080` for the 'destination port'. do **NOT** prefix the destination port with `localhost:'.

  I also manually added port 25565. **This one should be a 'local' forward, not a 'dynamic' forward.**

  To accomplish this, do the following:

  enter `25565` as the source port, and `localhost:25565` as the destination port. Select the `local` radio button (then hit `add`).

.

- **Steps to configure minecraft to use this tunnel**

  In the new minecraft launcher, edit your profile (use the aptly named `edit profile` button) or make a new one for tunneling (`new profile`) and click the checkbox next to `JVM Arguments`. In the box that is no longer greyed out, add the following string to the argument already there (should be `-Xmx1G`):

  `-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=8080`

  Now, the arguments will look like this:

  `-Xmx1G -DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=8080`

  Click `Save Profile`.

**Save your pUTTY session settings.**

- With your pUTTY terminal active (just log in, and you don't need to do anything else) start Minecraft under the profile you created/edited. Assuming you are tunneling to a valid host (in my case, a linux PC i own that is not behind such a draconian firewall), you should now have minecraft multiplayer running! Congratulations!

I initially learned how to do this by determining what this shellscript (https://gist.github.com/EspadaV8/1088594) did, and copying that functionality into pUTTY's settings.

The other answers didn't completely solve the problem, because they failed to realize that java doesn't follow the global windows proxy settings. My answer makes use of the little-known `-DsocksProxyHost` and `-DsocksProxyPort` arguments provided at initialization. For a http proxy or SSL proxy, use `-DhttpProxyHost` and `-DhttpProxyPort` options, or `-DhttpsProxyHost` and `-DhttpsProxyPort` arguments, respectively. I can confirm personal success using this method behind a proxy and a firewall :D